# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for MLP:

Tags: python, dataset, runtime-error, mnist

```
 File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1604, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for MLP:
    size mismatch for fc1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([627, 784]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([78, 784]).
    size mismatch for fc1.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([627]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([78]).
    size mismatch for fc2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([784, 627]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([784, 78]).
```

```
class MLP_MNIST(nn.Module):
    # classifier
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP_MNIST, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 250)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(250, 125)
        # self.fc4 = nn.Linear(125, 10)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(125, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
```

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
                def __init__(self):
                    compre_rate = compression_rate
                    super(MLP, self).__init__()
                    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, int(28 * 28 * compre_rate))
                    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(int(28 * 28 * compre_rate), 28 * 28)

               def forward(self, x):
                    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
                    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
                    # x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
                    x = self.fc1(x)
```

Comment: The error you are mentioning is happening when you are loading some weights into a model. These weights come from a model with different parameters, and hence don't have the right shape. Are you sure you are loading the correct weights into the correct model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.